# Jcrop button not working in safari or chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jcrop

I'm currently using Jcrop and we are experiencing issues with Chrome and Safari.

we can upload an image and the Jcrop binds to the image so i can drag the dimentions and using the inspect element i can confirm that the dimentions are correctly updated into the fields. However when i click the crop image button the event doesn't fire on chrome or safari. I have looked for issues but am unable to find it. As i have an ajax upload for the photo and loading the photo into colorbox i have had to use the following code:

The Cropping Section

```
$(document).on("submit", "#resize", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".loadgif").css("display", "none");
    var t = $("#resizeimage").val();
    var n = $("#w").val();
    var r = $("#h").val();
    var i = $("#x").val();
    var s = $("#y").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scripts/resizer.php",
        data: {
            image: t,
            w: n,
            h: r,
            x: i,
            y: s
        }
    }).done(function (e) {
        $("#images1").val(e)
    }).complete(function (e) {
        var t = $(".myform");
        t.reset();
    });
    $("#cropimage").colorbox.close()
});
```

The Upload Section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#formsubmit").click(function (e) {
        $(".loadgif").css("display", "block");
        e.preventDefault();
        var t = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display:none;"/>');
        $("body").append(t);
        var n = $(".myform");
        n.attr("action", "scripts/uploader.php");
        n.attr("method", "post");
        n.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        n.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
        n.attr("target", "postiframe");
        n.attr("file", $("#userfile").val());
        n.submit();
        $("#postiframe").load(function () {
            function e(e) {
                $("#x").val(e.x);
                $("#y").val(e.y);
                $("#w").val(e.w);
                $("#h").val(e.h)
            }

            function t() {
                if (parseInt($("#w").val())) return true;
                alert("Please select a crop region then press submit.");
                return false
            }
            iframeContents = $("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            $("#cropimage").html(iframeContents);
            $("#postiframe").remove();
            $.colorbox({
                width: "60%",
                inline: true,
                href: "#cropimage"
            });
            $(document).find("#postiframe").remove();
            $(function () {
                $("#cropbox").Jcrop({
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    onSelect: e
                })
            });
        })
    });
});
```

as the website does use a form that is for the product submission however i also had to use a form that submits for the jcrop so it will modify the form to work for the upload then after it will reset the form but i can't even get that far. As i said this works fine in I.E and in Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What appends if you change the `on('submit'` by `$('your_submit_button').on('click'`

Comment: so you mean the line reads $('your_submit_button').on('click', "#resize", function (e) instead?

Comment: Yes, it was that i mean, but i don't think it will be helpfull because the content of the `e` param would not been correct!

Comment: no it breaks on all browsers. thank you though

Comment: You was actually very close it still needed to be $(document) as it was bound outside of the original load however the it should of been $(document).on("click", "#button_link", function (e) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to replace

```
$(document).on("submit", "#resize", function (e) {
```

by

```
$(document).on("click", "#button_link", function (e) {
```